# Use magrittr dot placeholder IN FUNCTION DEFINITION to pass object via pipe operator to argument in arbitrary position by default?

Tags: r, magrittr

I want to define a function in a way that the `magrittr` pipe operator passes the object to the second argument by default.

```
library(magrittr)

foo <- function(a, b) c(a,b)
```

Pipe operator passes object to first argument of `foo`.

```
1 %>% foo(2)
```

Pipe passes object to second argument of foo when using the `.` placeholder.

```
1 %>% foo(2, .)
```

**Is there a way to build a function so that it directly has the `.` placeholder in its definition,
so that the pipe will use the second argument by default?** In pseudo code this would be 
something along the lines of:

```
foo2 <- function(a, b = <pipe arg placeholder>) {
    b = <process arg placeholder> 
    c(a, b)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `foo` doesn't "know" how the pipe was written
it just knows how it is called once *magrittr* has added the dot (if relevant)
so from the function itself we cannot differentiate implicit and explicit dots.

This issue aside we can just switch the 2 first arguments if the first one is a dot and return the evaluated modified call:

```r
library(magrittr)
foo <- function(a, b) {
  mc <- match.call()
  if(mc[[2]] == quote(.)) {
    mc[[2]] <- mc[[3]]
    mc[[3]] <- quote(.)
    return(eval.parent(mc))
  }
  c(a,b)
  }
1 %>% foo(2)
#> [1] 2 1
1 %>% foo(2, .)
#> [1] 2 1
# but also, because of disclaimer above
1 %>% foo(., 2)
#> [1] 2 1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It will need to be adjusted if `a` can take a default value and be left empty, and possibly other edge cases.

edit: I lied when I said `foo` doesn't know how the pipe was written, it's in the call stack and we can see it by calling `sys.call()` in the function, but I think the solution is convoluted enough as it is!

---

Another way would be to define a pipe that inserts in second position, it's a bit more flexible and possibly less surprising :

```r
foo <- function(a=2, b) {
  c(a,b)
}

`%>2%` <-
  function (lhs, rhs) {
    rhs_call <- insert_dot2(substitute(rhs))
    eval(rhs_call, envir = list(. = lhs), enclos = parent.frame())
  }

insert_dot2 <-
  function(expr, special_cases = TRUE) {
    if(is.symbol(expr) || expr[[1]] == quote(`(`)) {
      # if a symbol or an expression inside parentheses, make it a call with 
      # a missing first argument and a dot on second position
      expr <- as.call(c(expr,alist(x=)[[1]], quote(`.`)))
    } else if(length(expr) ==1) {
      # if a call without arg, same thing
      expr <- as.call(c(expr[[1]],alist(x=)[[1]], quote(`.`)))
    } else if (expr[[1]] != quote(`{`) &&
               all(sapply(expr[-1], `!=`, quote(`.`)))) {
      # if a call with args but no dot in arg, insert dot in second place first
      expr <- as.call(c(as.list(expr[1:2]), quote(`.`), as.list(expr[-(1:2)])))
    }
    expr
  }
1 %>2% foo(2)
#> [1] 2 1
1 %>2% foo(2, .)
#> [1] 2 1
1 %>2% foo(., 2)
#> [1] 1 2
1 %>2% foo()
#> [1] 2 1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

Note: piping to second is a bit weird, I'd rather pipe to last (it would have the same result for your question's example), if you want to pipe to last you would do :

```r
foo <- function(a=2, b) {
  c(a,b)
}

`%>last%` <-
  function (lhs, rhs) {
    rhs_call <- insert_dot_last(substitute(rhs))
    eval(rhs_call, envir = list(. = lhs), enclos = parent.frame())
  }

insert_dot_last <-
  function(expr, special_cases = TRUE) {
    if(is.symbol(expr) || expr[[1]] == quote(`(`)) {
      # if a symbol or an expression inside parentheses, make it a call with 
      # a dot arg
      expr <- as.call(c(expr, quote(`.`)))
    } else if(length(expr) ==1) {
      # if a call without arg, same thing
      expr <- as.call(c(expr[[1]], quote(`.`)))
    } else if (expr[[1]] != quote(`{`) &&
               all(sapply(expr[-1], `!=`, quote(`.`)))) {
      # if a call with args but no dot in arg, insert dot in last place
      expr <- as.call(c(as.list(expr), quote(`.`)))
    }
    expr
  }
1 %>last% foo(2)
#> [1] 2 1
1 %>last% foo(2, .)
#> [1] 2 1
1 %>last% foo(., 2)
#> [1] 1 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, 2nd was just to outline the issue, piping last is an easy to understand alternative. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

In this example the input to the pipe is used as the second argument to `f`.  We do have to use {...} but perhaps this is close enough.

```
f <- function(x, y = parent.frame()$.) x - y
12 %>% { f(20) }
## [1] 8
```

Comment: any chances to do this avoiding the curly braces?

Comment: We understand the question so it's pointless to keep repeating it. I think you are going to have to compromise a bit.  Another thing you could do is rewrite %>% to pass to the second argument.  If iyou explain why you want this maybe there is an alternate approach to the underlying problem.

Comment: If you slightly change the function definition and use `%$%` you can avoid the braces IF the lhs is a list or data frame : `f <- function(x, y = eval.parent(quote(.))) {x - y}; data.frame(foo=12) %$% f(20)`